# Getting output of a multiple commands and store them in a simple file using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a .txt file which containers multiple commands. I want to input the file, read the content and run  those commands line by line and retrieve output of each command in a single file using a powershell script. Can somebody help me with writing this script??

Comment: Rename your `.txt` file to `.ps1`, then run `file.ps1 > path\to\output.txt`

Comment: To add to Mathias' comment: if `file.ps1` is placed in the _current_ directory, you must call it as `.\file.ps1 ...`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was Solved Using the above solution